# Combining an array with multiple columns into a single column using Excel or Python

Tags: excel, concatenation

I am working with a large array of values in Excel. These values are organized vertically (starting at the top for each column) and span across 194 columns. I want to stitch each column together into a single column (so that I can copy/paste all of the values into a separate program for additional calculations). Basically, starting with the first column, I want to take the column on the right and add the values to the column on the left (so that the value at the top of the column being added comes after the value at the bottom of the column preceding it). I want to do this for all columns in the spreadsheet.

I haven't been able to figure out how to do this in Excel or through my Jupyter notebook (after converting the Excel file to a .csv and trying to use a loop to stitch the files together).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can do this easily in Power Query (available in Excel 2010+ and Office 365) if that is an option

Comment: Ok, thank you for the suggestion! I will see if I'm able to access Power Query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use Power Query (available in Excel 2010+ and Office 365), you can do it with just a few lines of code.

```
let

//change the table name in the next line to the real table name in your worksheet
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    oneCol = Table.FromList(List.Combine(Table.ToColumns(Source)),Splitter.SplitByNothing())
in
    oneCol
```

If your columns do not all have the same number of rows, you may have to `RemoveNulls` or do some other processing depending on the nature of your data and desired output

eg:

```
oneCol=Table.FromList(List.RemoveNulls(List.Combine(Table.ToColumns(Source))),Splitter.SplitByNothing())
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! Thank you. I think I've got it all figured out now. I really appreciate your help!